# Android Testing. A series of clicks using Espresso

Tags: android, testing

I'm new to Android UI testing.
My app is using a lot of fragmentation for instance:
Clicking on a button will replace the current fragment with another one.
When I do:

```
onView(withId(R.id.some_button)).perform(click());
```

the expresso framework tests clicking on that button.
BUT - espresso presses on the button and then does rollback, thus the button is pressed -> the new fragment is replacing the current one -> then it rolls back to the previous fragment.

Question:

How can I perform a series of clicks without rollback, so I could click on the new buttons that are present on the next fragment.
Sorry if the question is stupid, I need to understand how espresso works.
Thanks folks.

Comment: Come on guys !!! No one???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that it is simpler than I thought. 
You simply perform an action for example:

```
onView(withId(R.id.some_id_to_start_a_fragment)).perform(click());
```

then if you don't perform any other actions it will roll back, but you can continue clicking on the views that you assume appeared on the screen with the fragment.

```
onView(withId(R.id.some_view_from_the_fragment)).perform(click());
```

and it will perform this action continuously so you can do a lot of actions in series. 
Maybe for someone it'll be helpful.